# Using rsync to rename files during copying with --files-from?

Tags: rename, rsync

Using rsync, how can I rename files when copying with the --files-from argument? I have about 190,000 files, each of which need to be renamed when copying from source to destination. I plan to have the list of files in a text file to pass to the --files-from argument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to arbitrarily rename files with rsync. All rsync can do is move files to a different directory.

You must use a second tool either on the sending or receiving side to rename the files.

Comment: What if we are moving the files into the same directory?

Comment: then use something like `zmv` ^^

Answer (score 14):

Not entirely true... you CAN rename files enroute with rsync, but only if you rsync one file at a time, and set the --no-R --no-implied-dirs options, then explicitly set the destination name in the destination path.

But at that point, you may just want to use some other tool.

This, for example, would work:

```
rsync --no-R --no-implied-dirs
1.2.3.4::module/$FILENAME
/$PATH/$TOFILE/$NEWFILENAME
```

Comment: Actually, rsync is useful for a single file in some circumstances.  If the file is large, and has either only had minor changes, or has only been appended to, it's a good fit.

Comment: According to man page, `--no-implied-dirs` only affects how `--relative` works. And `--relative` is the same as `-R`. But you use `--no-R`, which makes me wonders what effect  `--no-implied-dirs` is supposed to have in that case?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Just realized that the question asks to actually rename the files for the transfer and does not try to solve the issue, that renamed files are copied even when they didn't changed (which was my concern in answer below).

For your question you can actually use an approach with the hard links. Instead of copying your source directory, create a new one as hard links to the same data using `cp --recursive --link <source> <renamed>` (the hard links do not take extra space on your disk) perhaps also with `--no-dereference` option to avoid following symbolic links.

Then rename the files in the `<renamed>/` directory as you wish, and upload them to the destination.

**Original answer:**

A think this trick using `--hard-links` should do exactly that.

Create a hardlink copy of your filenames within the source directory and upload it to the destination. Then rename the files as you please and upload the changes -- since the hardlinks are preserved, no data are actually transffered. Finally you can delete the directory with the hardlinks in your source, which will also vanish from the destination if you use `--delete` option in the `rsync`.

To illustrate it with a code look at the following output:

```
############## the initial backup
 $  rsync -av --hard-links --delete source backup/destination/
sending incremental file list
created directory backup/destination
source/
source/00_run
source/01_share
source/02_study
source/03_improve

sent 495 bytes  received 137 bytes  1,264.00 bytes/sec
total size is 160  speedup is 0.25

############## make hardlinks to the old names at the source
 $  cp --recursive --link {source,.oldnames} && mv .oldnames source

############## upload the hard links to the destination
 $  rsync -av --hard-links --delete source backup/destination/
sending incremental file list
source/
source/.oldnames/
source/.oldnames/00_run => source/00_run
source/.oldnames/01_share => source/01_share
source/.oldnames/02_study => source/02_study
source/.oldnames/03_improve => source/03_improve

sent 373 bytes  received 96 bytes  938.00 bytes/sec
total size is 320  speedup is 0.68

############## rename the files
 $  cd source/
 $  for f in *; do mv $f `echo $f | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`; done
 $  cd ..

############## upload the renamed files (the new names are linked to the old names)
 $  rsync -av --hard-links --delete source backup/destination/
sending incremental file list
deleting source/03_improve
deleting source/02_study
deleting source/01_share
deleting source/00_run
source/
source/00_RUN => source/.oldnames/00_run
source/01_SHARE => source/.oldnames/01_share
source/02_STUDY => source/.oldnames/02_study
source/03_IMPROVE => source/.oldnames/03_improve

sent 409 bytes  received 209 bytes  1,236.00 bytes/sec
total size is 320  speedup is 0.52

############## remove the links to the old names at the source and destination
 $  rm -r source/.oldnames/
 $  rsync -av --hard-links --delete source backup/destination/
sending incremental file list
deleting source/.oldnames/03_improve
deleting source/.oldnames/02_study
deleting source/.oldnames/01_share
deleting source/.oldnames/00_run
deleting source/.oldnames/
source/

sent 160 bytes  received 153 bytes  626.00 bytes/sec
total size is 160  speedup is 0.51
```